# Maximize number of key per b-tree node

Tags: c++, b-tree

I implemented a b-tree that only accepts the unique keys. I am trying to optimize the code so that each node has max number key stored.

For example, if I am inserting 1,2,3,4,5,6... in sequential order (t=3)

The node will be split after inserting 5 resulting...

```
     (3)
    /   \
(1|2)  (4|5)
```

Since the left child node can't put in anymore numbers, that node will forever contain at max of 2 node (if I keep adding keys at the end).

If I keep adding keys in order the result may look like this...

```
                    9
                 /     \
    (3       6   )      (   12       15      )
   /   \       \         /        \        \
(1|2)  (4|5)   (7|8)   (10|11)  (13|14)  (16|17)
```

I thought about borrowing neigbhour's key which or splitting the max key node from calculating where to split but it seems like doing so can affect the balance of the tree.

The reason I am doing this is to keep memory low as possible for more limited embedded hardware.

If there are better data structure recommendation please let me know.

Any suggestions would be great!
Thank you!

Comment: I don't recommend trees or linked lists in embedded systems, since the allocation and deallocation can fragment memory.  You may want to allocate your nodes from an array instead.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ balanced B-Tree example".

Comment: You may want to increase the nodes per page to reduce memory fragmentation issues.